# How to prove an isomorphism on sets that are not groups or rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $S\subset \mathbb{R^2}$ be a set which contains a basis of $\mathbb{R^2}$ and let an other set be defined by $$ S' := S \times \{0 \} = \{ (x,y,0) \in \mathbb{R^3}|(x,y)\in S \}.$$

I need to show that $O(S)\cong SO(S').$ It is not stated in the book, but I assume that with $O(S), SO(S')$ is meant the orthogonal group in $\mathbb{R^2}$ acting on the subset $S$ in terms of rotations, and $SO(S')$ is the special orthogonal group acting on a subset of $\mathbb{R^3}.$ First of all $S, S'$ are only sets and not necessarily subgroups. I guess that the cardinality of both $S$ and $S'$ is the same. I do not know how to define a homomorphism on sets that are not necessarily groups. Can you provide some insight what I have to show or provide a solution to the problem ? Thanks.

Comment: You do not need to define a homomorphism between $S%$ and $S'$, but rather between the groups $O(S)$ and $SO(S)$. So the title is perhaps a misunderstanding. The question is, how the orthogonal group on $S$ is defined. Can you add this in more detail, or find it in your lecture notes?

Comment: Thanks. It is not stated explicitly, how the group action on the sets $S, S'$ is defined. I assume that the orthogonal group $O$ acts on the vectors of the set $S$ by means of rotations and reflections, whereas $SO$ by rotations on the vectors of $S'.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map
$$O(S)\to SO(S'),\quad M\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}M&0\\0&\det M\end{pmatrix}$$
is clearly an injective morphism.

It is surjective because $S$ contains a basis of $\Bbb R^2.$